# How to inject external environment variables to jenkins configuration and pipeline jobs?

Tags: jenkins, docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

We are running Jenkins inside a docker container using docker-compose.

Out goal is to be able to run production and test environments that are configurable by environment variables given to the docker-compose command.

We define several environment variables in the docker-compose.yml file, such as:

```
environment:
         - gitlabrepourl=http://url-of-our-git-repo/repo-name
         - hosturl=http://jenkins-host-url
```

The environment variables are present inside the container when running bash shell, but we are having problems using them in Jenkins configuration and in our pipeline script.

Some examples:

- When creating a pipeline job and choosing "Pipeline script from SCM" -> git -> Repository URL = ${gitlabrepourl}. The pipeline job is able to clone the repository in order to get the Jenkinsfile, but when running 'checkout scm' it fails because the ${gitlabrepourl} is not resolved. (Jenkins bug maybe??)
- When trying to use the environment variables in Jenkins system configurations, they do not get resolved in all places. e.g. when trying to use ${hosturl} as our 'Jenkins URL' configuration, it is not resolved. or when trying to use ${gitlabrepourl} in our 'Gitlab host URL' configuration, it does not pass the connection test.

Summary:

1. How can we use environment variables in jenkins configuration, and how can we know which fields support using environment variables?
2. How to inject environment variables present in the docker container into the pipeline script?
3. Any way that can help us achieve any of our goals would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way, but this is how I did it for docker:

I created a `.env` file with the following:

```
CONFLUENCE_VERSION=6.1.1
MYSQL_CONNECTOR_VERSION=5.1.41
```

Docker-compose will automatically pull those in as environment variables.

I then passed them as args to the build section of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
      - CONFLUENCE_VERSION=${CONFLUENCE_VERSION}
      - MYSQL_CONNECTOR_VERSION=${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_VERSION}
```

Read CONFLUENCE_VERSION from `.env` in Jenkinsfile:

```
CONF_VER = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'grep -e "CONFLUENCE_VERSION" .env | awk -F\'=\' \'{print $2}\'').trim()
```

Comment: That's also the only way I found so far

Answer (score 0):

You can inject variables from some file, for example
[image]
.dockerproperties - file in you SCM repo
and if in this file you have line
varName1=test
you can use it in format ${varName1}
also, if you want use some info from git, like tag, or commit id, you should install plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin

Comment: The Inject environment variables didn't work for me for some reason.  I had it defined in Jenkinsfile under properties.